# Pass data.Data(Uri) from OnActivityResult To another Activity To show the image in Imageview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When I upload an image from the gallery the code works fine, but the problem is when I want to show the image in the imageview of another activity

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Canceled) return;

    // make it available in the gallery
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
    if (_file != null)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file);
        mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
        SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        // display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display
        // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory 
        // and cause the application to crash.
            _imageView.SetImageURI(contentUri);
    }
}
```

ContentUri stores the actual image uri and I want to retrieve it on another activity but how would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried ways of doing this yourself and had trouble? You should try it first and post with questions when you have problems if you can't find the solution elsewhere on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the imageview using bitmap.
Following link helps you to get the bitmap from camera Activity

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/